# Setting section counter

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing a lab report and there are four "questions" corresponding to lab instructions 6.1 through to 6.4. How can I set the section counter to start at 6.1 and then continue in 0.1 increments? I would like to avoid using environments like enumerate because I have tikz figures and some of the formatting I have already done elsewhere in the document may be lost. I am using the report class. Here is the MWC:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\begin{document}
\title{REPORT}
\author{student ID}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{} \paragraph{6.1}
\section{} \paragraph{6.2}
\section{} \paragraph{6.3}
\section{} \paragraph{6.4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated. Why don't you use `\subsection` instead?

Comment: Good idea. I'll use the solution from @kan below to start at 6 and      \subsection to continue incrementing by 0.1.

Comment: @jacob I am not following what you mean. Mine is basically a hack. And a very dirty one at that. It really depends on what you want at the end. But, please be warned that, you should use both answers with end result in mind.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not simply use subsections after setting the section counter to 6?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{6}
\subsection{First question}
\subsection{Second question}
\subsection{Third question}
\end{document}
```