# Custom counter in section with multiple numbers

Tags: sectioning, counters, section-titles

I'm writing an article but I have to start as "*2.4 Chapter Title*" (the final pdf output has to be merged with the other chapters).

I know I could shift all the headings and instead of starting with "Section" I could start from a "Subsection" adding `\setcounter{section}{2}` and `\setcounter{subsection}{3}` and therefore doing the trick of the correct numbering (as proposed in [the first answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111504/setting-section-counter)).

But I'll end up using a subparagraph and all the title sizes are scaled down (due to the absence of the "Section" title style)

Is there any alternative solution which could give me back the possibility to use also the "Section" environment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your portion will be included in the final article. I can imagine the editor creating the main document and then using `\input` to collect your, and others, portions. If this is the case then just start with your `\section`, not bothering about the numbering, and when it is `\input` in the final document in the correct place the numbering will automatically adjust.

For your proofreading create a file, say `mysection.tex` which starts with your `\section` and then a main file like:

```
% tryportion.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{mysection}
\end{document}
```

and process `tryportion`.

Following your helpful comment which goes towards clarifying the assembly process you could structure your portion of the document like:

```
% secnumprob.tex SE 540206

\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % (current) chapter
\setcounter{section}{3} % previous section number

\section{Title Mysection 1 (2.4?)}
Some text.
\subsection{Title Subsection 1 (2.4.1?)}
More text, and so on.
\section{Next section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see the point. Actually the final pdf output has to be merged with the other sections (not all the authors are using latex as you can imagin). I'll therefore have to send my pdf to the main author who will join all the parts...

Comment: @Chamaeleon Following your comment I have added a second answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried and I realized that I probably did not express myself properly. I adapted the question including some additional information to clarify better my situation. In any case your second solution essentially is to change the documentclass to gain one additional level XD

Comment: @Chamaeleon You say that you have to provide a PDF file to the editor/compiler. He won't care if you use the `article` or `report` or ... class in preparing your PDF. My second answer provides the basis for the PDF you have to supply. Please accept it. What about page numbers in the final publication? How will submissions be neatly embedded in the final document with no glaring spaces between them? Has your editor considered these aspects? I am concerned  about the process of assembling the final document.

Comment: @Chamaeleon now you have completely changed the question. I'll leave the answer up to you. --- GOM

Comment: If I re-post this as a new question would you be so kind to provide a possible solution? Then I can accept that one as useful answer as well. (BTW, I don't know what GOM stands for)

Comment: @Chamaeleon Maybe yes, maybe no, but it would open the possibility that others might provide answers. GOM = Grumpy Old Man.