# Customize chapter number in multiple levels

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I'm writing a portion of an article (using the `article` class) and my part has to be included as "*2.4 Chapter Title*". The final pdf output has to be merged with the other chapters. Considering that not all the authors are using latex I'll therefore have to send my pdf to the main author who will join all the parts.

We'll have a final document structure like the following (the chapter I have to wrtite is in bold):

---

1 "Main title of the article part #1"

2 "Main title of the article part #2"

2.3 "Other author's chapter title"

**2.4 "My chapter title"**

- 2.4.1 Title Section 1
- 2.4.1.1 Title Subsection 1
- 2.4.2 Title Subsection 2
- etc...
- up to the paragraph level indentation

2.5 "Other author's chapter title"

---

I know I could shift all the headings and instead of starting with "Section" I could start from a "Subsection" adding `\setcounter{section}{2}` and `\setcounter{subsection}{3}` and therefore doing the trick of the correct numbering (as proposed in [the first answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111504/setting-section-counter)).

But I'll end up using a subparagraph and all the title sizes are scaled down (due to the absence of the "Section" title style)

Is there any alternative solution which could give me back the possibility to use also the "Section" environment?

I also tried to use the `report` documentclass, here my minimal working example with the use of `\setcounter`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{\textbf{{\Huge 2.4 ``Main Title''}}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}\setcounter{section}{3}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section[Title section 1]{Title section 1}
\subsection[Title subsection 1]{Title subsection 1}
\subsection[Title subsection 2]{Title subsection 2}
\subsubsection[Title subsubsection 1]{Title subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection[Title subsubsection 2]{Title subsubsection 2}
\subsubsection[Title subsubsection 3]{Title subsubsection 3}

\section[Title section 2]{Title section 2}
\subsection[Title subsection 2.1]{Title subsection 2.1}

\section{Title section 3}
\section{Title section 4}

\end{document}
```

Here I provide the revised output:

[image: Revised output from MWE]

From what I understand I would have to start from a `\subsection` instead of `\chapter` to get the proper numbering.

Comment: ‘Sectiob’ is not an environment, but a command?. Whye don't you use the `report` class? It has chapters, contrary to `article`

Comment: I actually don't mind to use `report` or `article`, what I can not get is the proper numbering in all the title levels (starting from the highest with 2.4, up to the paragraph)

Comment: I see (I think). If I've well understood, shouldn't it be enough to add at the very beginning `\setcounter{chapter}{2}\setcounter{section}{3} \section{My chapter title}` to obtain what you want?

Comment: The fact is that I need total 6 title levels, and in this way I can reach only 4 I think, right?

Comment: If you use `report`,  you have 6 levels by default, not counting `\part`  (from chapter to subparagraph).

Comment: I see, I'll try again. I was simply thinking to put two numbers ("2.4") in one level instead of just one each ("2")

Comment: This being said, having  an $n$ levels numbering system  with a bib n can easily be heavy.

Comment: Ok, I tried and seems to still miss one number (I updated the question with a working example)

Comment: Does 2.4 correspond  to something like `\thepart.\thechapter in the real document`, or is it purely fancy?

Comment: I don't know exactly what `\thepart` or `\thechapter` is but I would say 2.4 it is part of the main title and has to be repeated in each section's title (as in the example picture)

Comment: `\thepart` is simply the current part number displaying. Similarly for `\thechapter`. In this case, you simply can add  `\renewcommand{\thesection}{2.4.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`.

Comment: Yes, that's the command I was missing, tanks! So in this case to use the `article` or `report` class doesn't matter right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: This is remarkably like your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540206 but without referring to the answer to that question.